# Render two navigators

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

There is a Login.js module, with this module the user can log in. If the user data is correct, then the user switches to another Secured.js module. For switching from the module to the module I use StackNavigator. In the Secured.js module, Tabs should be displayed below. For this I use TabNavigator. The problem is that when I try to render tabs, it does not work for me, because React Native says that two navigators can not be created on one page. I tried to google, but I could not find anything worthwhile, except for the advice to update React Native, saying "this is a bug of the old version" (I tried too, but it didn't help). Is there any ideas how I can fix it?

[image: The error]

Secured.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  ScrollView,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList
} from 'react-native';
// Import getNews function from news.js
import { getNews } from '../screens/news';
// We'll get to this one later
import Article from '../components/Article';
import Tabs from '../screens/Tabs';

export default class Secured extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
   title: "Neuigkeiten",
   headerTintColor: "#FF0000",
   headerLeft: null,
}; 
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { articles: [], refreshing: true };
  this.fetchNews = this.fetchNews.bind(this);
}
// Called after a component is mounted
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchNews();
}

fetchNews() {
  getNews()
  .then(articles => this.setState({ articles, refreshing: false }))
  .catch(() => this.setState({ refreshing: false }));
 }

 handleRefresh() {
   this.setState(
   {
    refreshing: true
  },
   () => this.fetchNews()
  );
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <View>
  <FlatList
    data={this.state.articles}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <Article article={item} />}
    keyExtractor={item => item.url}
    refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
    onRefresh={this.handleRefresh.bind(this)}
  />
    <View><Tabs /></View>
  </View>
);
}
}
```

Tabs.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Secured from '../screens/Secured';
import Page1 from '../screens/Page1';
import Page2 from '../screens/Page2';
import Page3 from '../screens/Page3';

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
///  Secured: {screen:Secured,},
 Page1: {screen:Page1,},
 Page2: {screen:Page2,},
 Page3: {screen:Page3,}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it's not all happening because of react-native version is not updated. it's all about react-native navigation wrong use.

Let me explain you with two examples, one is wrong way similar with your case and second one is highly prefer, correct way to use navigators.

In React Native Navigation,

**WRONG WAY**

```
export default App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    /* In the root component we are rendering the app navigator */
    return <AppNavigator />;
  }
}

const AuthenticationNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  SignIn: SignInScreen,
  ForgotPassword: ForgotPasswordScreen,
});


class AuthenticationScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <AuthenticationNavigator />
    );
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Auth: AuthenticationScreen, // This screen renders a navigator!
  Home: HomeScreen,
});
```

In a screen inside of the navigator we are rendering another navigator You should avoid this! It will have its own navigation state and be unable To interact with any parent navigator, eg: it would not know the route "Home" exists

**CORRECT & HIGHLY RECOMMENDED WAY**

```
export default App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppNavigator />;
  }
}

const AuthenticationNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  SignIn: SignInScreen,
  ForgotPassword: ForgotPasswordScreen,
});

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  /* 
   * Rather than being rendered by a screen component, the
   * AuthenticationNavigator is a screen component
   */
  Auth: AuthenticationNavigator,
  Home: HomeScreen,
});
```

**IN YOUR CASE**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Secured from '../screens/Secured';
import Page1 from '../screens/Page1';
import Page2 from '../screens/Page2';
import Page3 from '../screens/Page3';

const Tabnav =  createBottomTabNavigator({
///  Secured: {screen:Secured,},
 Page1: {screen:Page1,},
 Page2: {screen:Page2,},
 Page3: {screen:Page3,}
});
```

and return the Tabnav in render function , instead of export the default. because we can't export more than one in one place.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped me a lot!

Comment: my pleasure my mate